# Baby mango tree leaf dying

Tags: fruit-trees, seedlings, mango

I’ve recently planted a mango tree sprouted from a store bought mango seed, which was just over a month ago. From the beginning, it was a little weird as it only grew one leaf. It seemed like there was another small leaf shooting out from the side, but it never grew into a full one. A couple days ago, I noticed that its leaf was beginning to wrinkle and dry from the sides, and this condition has gotten worse now. The affected part had a darker color and was not as smooth. It seems that the tree will die. [image]

I’ve only fertilized it with those Miracle Grow Plant Food Spikes, and I’ve since repotted the plant but to no avail, so I don’t think it’s due to fertilizer burn or the type of dirt used. However, when I was replanting it, I noticed that it does not have much root, but I didn’t really notice any root rot.

[image: The mango tree as of today]

I’m not really sure what is going on here. I suspect that there might just be something wrong with the seed to start. Any thoughts on what’s happening?